# Has the PyFacebook library been deprecated, discontinued or replaced?

Tags: facebook, pyfacebook

Every link I find for the tutorials leads me to this:

http://developers.facebook.com/search?q=User:PyFacebook_Tutorial

Which doesn't work. Couldn't find anything on facebook developers... closest guess is that it was replaced by:

https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk

Anyone know for sure?

Comment: Having same issue. Frustrating that Facebook has such poor support for Python.

Comment: Also wondering what's going on. pyFacebook and co should also put some kind of notice alerting people not to waste their time with their outdated stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PyFacebook is has been discontinued. The Facebook dev [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) page links directly to the python-sdk project on github, interestingly there's no mention of python on this [SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) at all.